# How does killing Barron affect the timeline in Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children?

Tags: time-travel, miss-peregrines-home-for-peculiar

In the movie "Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children", Mr. Barron kidnaps Miss Peregrine in order to use her in his immortality experiment.  With Miss Peregrine gone, the time loop she created in September 1943 collapses, stranding Jake and the other kids in 1943.  So to rescue Miss Peregrine, they take a ship to Blackpool, where Miss Avicet's loop in January 2016 is located.  While aboard the ship, Emma says this to Jake:

> Jake, you know what this means don't you? ... We have to get to our own time but you don't.  You can continue to live in 2016... If we kill Barron, he'll be gone but time will carry on.  He won't go to Florida, Abe won't die, and you can go home."

My question is, how would killing Barron save the life of Jake's grandfather Abe?  Abe died in July 2016, so theoretically killing a version of Barron from before then would prevent Abe's death.  But that's not what happens; in Blackpool Barron speaks about Abe's death:

> I tracked Abe Portman for months.  All I needed was a few minutes to get the location of Miss Peregrine's loop from him.  But no, Mathus couldn't wait.  And instead, I had to masquerade as a psychiatrist for three weeks in Florida.

So if Barron has already participated in the Florida events, how will killing Bareon mean that "he won't go to Florida [and] Abe won't die"?

Is it supposed to be that if you die within a time loop you get erased from the timeline or something?  This is mighty *peculiar*, no pun intended.

Comment: Instead of repeatedly reopen-voting this question and having your vote either age away or be declined by the rest of the community, it might help if you could explain *why* this isn't a duplicate of the other question and *how* it asks a different question, either by commenting, bringing it to meta, or changing the question in order to flesh out the supposed difference a little more. Stubbornly smashing the reopen button every few months doesn't seem to be all too fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if they kill Barron in january 2016 (the loop they're in), he won't be able to exist in july 2016, being impossible the killing of Abe.

So, they are in a loop from the past, that means that the "now" (july) has already happend, Abe has been killed... that's why Barron acknowledged the killing... but if Barron dies in january... the future (july... so actually the real present) won't exist as we know it... and Abe won't die.

Comment: I agree that seems to be what the movie wants, but it's rubbish.  If tomorrow I travel back in time to 1912 and die there, that wouldn't prevent me from being born in the 70's and living until my sudden disappearance in 2017 (and all the things I've done within that time).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding with a loop in this movie is something that is created in relative to its existing timeline for a short time. This timeline still develops after its loop where they, the peculiars, are avoided to live in with the help of their Ymbryne. That is, it is possible to "travel" forward in time as long as that timeline develops (and when they are in loop preservation otherwise their age is affected greatly), and it is possible to "travel" back in time through that loop from the existing future. Of course, travellig only works for the peculiars. In that loop, it looks like the peculiars are meant to do something in order to stabilize the timeline.

> Barron found a loop (of Miss Peregrine) with the Hollow (Malthus). Malthus was the one who killed Abe in 2016, long after Abe sent a letter for Miss Peregrine about the (new) loop in London. When Malthus was killed in loop-1943, this created a new and unique timeline in which Malthus no longer exist in compared to the previous timeline. Since the loop was destroyed, the peculiars were living normally in that unique timeline. Note that since they were saving Miss Peregrine, it shows that she already was a part of that timeline with other Hollows. Additionally, this (unique) timeline might explain why Jake from the future didn't meet the earlier Jake in this case.